# Grouping nodes of the same label by parameter

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to graph databases, so apologies if I get some of the correct terminology wrong.

I'm using Neo4j and have a dataset made up of - mostly - one kind of node. These nodes have a variety of parameters and relationships between each other and the other labeled nodes in the graph.

To give a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve, let's assume I have a label of "Person". Each Person has a parameter named "gender", which will have a value of "male" or "female". What's the best practice if I want to run a query that will return all males in one variable, and all females in the other? Should they be separate labels? That seems like a bad idea given the parameters on each are identical.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, I say Labels are for properties where something either is or isn't that, and time won't change that. Gender is a bit weird with that though. If you are using genetic gender, Labels would be easier/better. For gender identity, use an indexed property. (Labels are basically an index, so will behave almost identically to property indexes) Just food for thought

Answer (score 2):

Since the neo4j DB maintains label count statistics, using `Male` and `Female` labels will get you those counts immediately -- without even needing to do any node queries.

For example, this query gets the number of `Male` nodes from the statistics:

```
MATCH (:Male)
RETURN COUNT(*) AS males
```

*However, the current Cypher planner seems to refuse to use the statistics a second time in the same query (based on my [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) runs), so the following query will actually scan the DB for `Female` nodes. Hopefully this can be improved in future Cypher planners.*

```
MATCH (m:Male)
WITH COUNT(m) AS males
MATCH (f:Female)
RETURN males, COUNT(f) AS females
```

[UPDATE 1]

However, as suggested by @InverseFalcon, using `UNION ALL` does cause the statistics to be used every time:

```
MATCH (m:Male) RETURN {male: COUNT(m)} AS counts
UNION ALL
MATCH (f:Female) RETURN {female: COUNT(f)} AS counts
```

[UPDATE 2]

If you want to get the actual nodes instead of the counts, then there are 2 answers with about the same performance (as shown by their `PROFILE`s).

1. You can use `Male` and `Female` labels:

   ```
   MATCH (m:Male)
   WITH COLLECT(m) AS males
   MATCH (f:Female)
   RETURN males, COLLECT(f) AS females
   ```
2. You can create an index on `:Person(gender)`:

   ```
   MATCH (m:Person {gender: 'male'})
   WITH COLLECT(m) AS males
   MATCH (f:Person {gender: 'female'})
   RETURN males, COLLECT(f) AS females
   ```

   However, this approach would require more storage, since you'd have to store the gender property with every node.

Comment: In the meantime, here's a neat cypher trick which will utilize the counts store using UNION ALL: `MATCH (m:Male)
RETURN {male:COUNT(m)} AS counts
UNION ALL
MATCH (f:Female)
RETURN {female:COUNT(f)} AS counts`

Comment: I'm looking for the actual nodes to be returned rather than only their counts, but thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one label `Person` for both with `gender` property.

The query below will return a `List` with two elements, each a `List` as well. The first element is for `males` and the second is `females`

```
MATCH (male {gender:'male'})
WITH COLLECT(male) AS maleList
MATCH (female {gender:'female'})
RETURN maleList, COLLECT(female)
```

I'm not sure if it is the best query. But it should return you what you need